# What is the best way to execute a bulk update of all records in a large table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is the best way to execute a bulk update of all records in a large table in MySQL?

During the sanitization process, we are updating all rows in the users table, which has 28M rows, to mask a few columns.  This is currently taking right around 2 hours to complete in a rake task, and the AWS session expiration is also 2 hours.  If the rake task takes longer than the session expiration, the build will fail.

Due to a large number of records, we are updating 25K rows at a time by using find_in_batches, and then update_all in the results.  We throttle between each batch by sleeping for 0.1s to avoid high CPU.

So the question is, is there any way we can optimize the bulk update further, or shall we increase the AWS session expiration to 3 hours?

One option could be to batch by id ranges, rather than by exact batch sizes.  So update between id 1-100000, followed by 100001-200000, and so on.  This avoids the large sets of ids being passed around.  As there will be gaps in the ids, each batch would be a different size, but this might not be an issue.

Thanks for your input.

Comment: What would be wrong with plain old good SQL query to update everything at once? It should drastically decrease the update time.

Comment: You should post the table structure here and the update query then we can give advice.

Answer (score 0):

For such large updates overhead of fetching records and instantiating AR objects is very significant (and also there'll be slowdown from GC), fastest way to execute - is to write raw sql query that will do the update (or use `update_all` to construct it, which is very similar, but allows to use scopes/joins by relations).